# How to use wireshark to decode SSL stream from remote API server?

Tags: tls, wireshark

I'm trying to troubleshoot some issues with what my code is sending to a remote API (over https). I've seen a ton of articles on Wireshark and decoding SSL, but they all make up their own test server which is useless to me. I need to know how to decrypt SSL streams to/from a server I don't control. How do I do this?

Comment: so, this: https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL ?

Comment: @schroeder Correct, it doesn't explain where to obtain the key from

Comment: Read the section called: Using the (Pre)-Master-Secret

Comment: Tried that. The key log file did nothing. It had a bunch of `CLIENT_RANDOM` entries in it. Pointing Wireshark to it did absolutely nothing.

Comment: The problem is, once I set up Firefox to log the pre-master-secret, I go to `https://api.whatever.net`.. is that it? Is the key logged to the file? I tried that and it didn't work. The documentation isn't clear about where to surf or what to do to properly populate the key file

Comment: Ok. You need to include what you've tried and what the results are. It looks like you're close.